# Argument separation in bash/command prompt

Tags: bash, cmd, arguments

the other day I ran the following piece of code on the windows `cmd`:

```
$java -cp . myProgram > output.txt
```

I could do the same in unix bash.

My question is the following:

- How is it that `>` and `output.txt` are not passed as an argument to `myProgram`?
- What if I wanted my program to receive `>` as an argument?

Comment: my guess would be that the command is parsed before hand and the parser or whatever has a lookup table for the symbol '>' and thus separates the arguments, is it anything like it?

Comment: For `bash`, read the first few pages in `man bash`, especially around "metacharacter" and "SHELL GRAMMAR".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metacharacter `>` is processed by the shell, and this character and the following filename are not included in the arguments when running the program. If you want it to be passed literally to the program, you need to quote it.

```
java -cp . myProgram ">" output.txt
```